# Python doesn't see the module installed with apt-get

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-fontforge
```

installs with no error

```
Preparing to unpack .../python-fontforge_20120731.b-7.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-fontforge (20120731.b-7.1) over (20120731.b-7.1) ...
Setting up python-fontforge (20120731.b-7.1) ...
```

but python still is unable to see the module

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/smoothscan-fontgen.py", line 23, in <module>
    import fontforge
ImportError: No module named fontforge
```

I install it with apt-get since pip doesn't find it

Looking in the lib I see this:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fontforge-1.0.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fontforge.so
```

python version:

```
Python 2.7.11 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

I want to mention that this happened after conda updated my python version

Comment: Are you on a virtualenv?

Comment: @NeoVe No I am not

Comment: @muddyfish but pip doesn't have fontforge

Comment: are you sure you are using the same system python?

Comment: `python --version` ?

Comment: How do you invoke `smoothscan-fontgen.py`? What is the first line of that file? What is the result of `dpkg -L python-fontforge | egrep /fontforge.so`. Edit `smoothscan-fontgen.py`. Before the `import`, add: `import sys` / `print (sys.path)` / `print (sys.version)` / `print ('/usr/lib/python2.7' in sys.path)`. What do you get?

Comment: @gerosalesc see edit

Comment: One last chore: `which python`.

Comment: @Robᵩ  `/usr/bin/python`, smoothscan program calls it, but it worked before installing a package with conda

Comment: `conda updated my python version` you gave yourself an answer there

Comment: I wonder if `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal` would fix this. I'm not suggesting OP try this without considering the consequences, just thinking out loud.

Comment: @Robᵩ I tried  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7` but no luck I will try you sugestion once I have the apt free from trying the most voted answer, I will come back here with feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you reinstall your original python installation unless you want something else broken in your system:

```
for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | egrep -v 'deinstall' | egrep python | awk '{print $1}'`; do  apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done
```

This will reinstall everything related to python and Python itself. Taken from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=735693)

Comment: I takes a while I will be back with an answer

Comment: This has fixed the issues, but it took around 2-3 hours

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this (not tested):

```
sudo apt-get install fontforge python-fontforge
```

Then:

```
python -c 'import fontforge; print "FontForge works in Python"'
```

Tell me if that works, Thank You

**EDIT**

Since it appears to be installed, try running it like this:

```
fontforge -lang=py -script my_script.py
```

**SECOND EDIT**

Maybe the fontforge you are using is not built with python support, if you download the code, please try this:

```
$ ./configure --enable-pyextension
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Then you could use it from inside python console:

```
>>> import fontforge
```

More info: [Compile fontforge with python support](http://fontforge.github.io/python.html#extension)

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
fontforge is already the newest version (20120731.b-7.1).
python-fontforge is already the newest version (20120731.b-7.1).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named fontforge

Comment: @Works when you call trough fontforge, but I cannot change smoothscan

Comment: Mmm okay, I've edited my answer again, check it out, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fontforge python-fontforge
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ufo2otf/0.1.0b